# Web host deleted webpage after 30 days and need to recover

Tags: web-hosting

I've allowed web host to delete my website, but I've now decided that I need to keep it. Since it was more than 30 days ago it is no longer recoverable according to the host. How can I recover the site? I do not have a backup of the site.

Comment: you don't have it, they don't have it, where do you think it's going to come from?

Comment: Some good hosting companies keeps the backup for a short period of time. Try emailing them first.

Comment: With all due respect if you don't have a copy and you know they don't, I am not entirely sure what you think our magic answer can be.

Answer (score 2):

The [Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) may have grabbed enough of your site that you can recover some or all of it.  Type in your site's old URL to see if their crawler archived your site and now will make it available to you.